# Problem of "PERMISSION_DENIED" on Firestore get due to security rule

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My Android Java application first creates a Firebase account (email with password) with `AuthUI.getInstance()` if the user has to sign up. When the account is created, a dialog informs the user he received a verification email and he has to click on the verification link in the email. When this is done by the user, he can then close the dialog and go on with the configuration of his account in Firestore.

But all the requests on Firestore documents protected by security rule like

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email != null && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
```

fail with

> com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

If the user closes the application, restarts it and re-authenticates, then its works (no problem of permission for the Firestore requests).

I made several tests. If I change the security rule as

```
allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email != null;
```

Everything works, but it is less secure from my point of view since there is no warranty the email is verified. It seems Firestore is still not aware the account is verified.

Here is a sample of an Activity :

```
package foo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Source;
import com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions;
import com.google.firebase.functions.HttpsCallableReference;
import com.google.firebase.functions.HttpsCallableResult;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import fr.cinfo.planartis.R;

public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private static final String VERIFICATION_EMAIL_SENT_TIMESTAMP_KEY = "verificationEmailSentTimestamp";
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startUserSignInActivity();
        } else {
            performEmailVerification();
        }
    }

    void startUserSignInActivity() {
        startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(Collections.singletonList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()))
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false, true)
                .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls("https://localhost/terms.html", "https://localhost/privacy.html")
                .build(),
            SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, @Nullable final Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) { // ERRORS
                // ... do something
                finish();
                return;
            }
            performEmailVerification();
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    void performEmailVerification() {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()) {
            // Everything is OK
            checkSomethingOnFirestore();
            return;
        }

        final DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.document("users/" + firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        documentReference.get(Source.DEFAULT).addOnCompleteListener((Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                final DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = task.getResult();
                if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
                    // Check if the first verification email was sent
                    final Object timestamp = userSnapshot.get(VERIFICATION_EMAIL_SENT_TIMESTAMP_KEY);
                    if (timestamp == null) {
                        firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> validationEmailTask) -> {
                            if (validationEmailTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                final Timestamp now = Timestamp.now();
                                documentReference.update(VERIFICATION_EMAIL_SENT_TIMESTAMP_KEY, now).addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> updateUserAccountTask) -> {
                                    if (!updateUserAccountTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                    }
                                    displayWarningAboutValidation();
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                // email not sent, so display message
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                displayInformationDialog(this, "Unable to send a verification email", null).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        displayWarningAboutValidation();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "We are finalizing your account creation\nPlease wait a few seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    final HttpsCallableReference httpsCallableReference = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().getHttpsCallable("finalizeUserAccount");
                    httpsCallableReference.setTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    httpsCallableReference.call(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).continueWith((Task<HttpsCallableResult> task12) -> {
                        if (!task12.isSuccessful()) {
                            displayInformationDialog(this, "The finalization of your account failed.", (DialogInterface dialog, int id) -> {
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                finish();
                            }).show();
                            return null;
                        }

                        displayInformationDialog(this, "A new verification email was sent", (final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) -> {
                            // Reload current user
                            firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload().addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task1) -> {
                                if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                                    performEmailVerification();
                                }
                                else {
                                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });

                        });
                        return null;
                    });
                }
            }
            else {
                displayInformationDialog(this, "Problem with the server", (DialogInterface dialog, int id) -> {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    finish();
                }).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkSomethingOnFirestore() {
        firestore.collection("users").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).collection("documents").get().addOnCompleteListener(this, (Task<QuerySnapshot> task) -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {  // <======================================== PERMISSION_DENIED exception !!!!!!
                displayInformationDialog(this, "Problem on Firestore", (final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) -> {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    finish();
                })
                .show();
                return;
            }
            // Go on and do the job: for instance display the GUI or anything else
        });
    }

    private void displayWarningAboutValidation() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("Read the verification email we sent and click on the link inside the email")
            .setPositiveButton("I understand", (DialogInterface dialog, int id) -> firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload().addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task) -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    performEmailVerification();
                }
                else {
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    finish();
                }
            }))
            .setNeutralButton("Send back a verification email", (final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) -> firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener((final Task<Void> task) -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // email sent
                    displayInformationDialog(this, "A new verification email was sent", (final DialogInterface dialog12, final int which12) -> {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        finish();
                    }).show();

                    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload().addOnCompleteListener((Task<Void> task1) -> {
                        if (task1.isSuccessful()) {
                            performEmailVerification();
                        }
                        else {
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // email not sent, so display message
                    displayInformationDialog(this, "Unable to send a new verification email", (final DialogInterface dialog1, final int which1) -> {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        finish();
                    }).show();
                }
            }))
            .show();
    }

    private AlertDialog displayInformationDialog(final Context context, final CharSequence message, final DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveButtonOnclickListener) {
        return new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context).setCancelable(false).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("I understand", positiveButtonOnclickListener).setTitle("Planartis").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_toolbar).show();
    }

}
```

Is the behaviour of Firestore correct ? What can I change in order to avoid restart of the application and re-authentication (user-friendliness) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google:

> Firebase Security Rules stand between your data and malicious users. You can write simple or complex rules that protect your app's data to the level of granularity that your specific app requires.
>
> Firebase Security Rules leverage extensible, flexible configuration languages to define what data your users can access for Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, and Cloud Storage. Firebase Realtime Database Rules leverage JSON in rule definitions, while Cloud Firestore Security Rules and Firebase Security Rules for Cloud Storage leverage a unique language built to accommodate more complex rules-specific structures.

**This is your main problem:** If the user is not account verified you perform some Firestore related task. However, if he is not verified you again get the email from Firestore. But your security rules describe that you should not be able to access the database unless you're account verified. That's where the code fails. This is your error:

```
void performEmailVerification() {
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()) {
        // Everything is OK, perform your task
        checkSomethingOnFirestore();
        return;
    }
    
    //User not verified, but you still get a database reference and try to get the email.
    final DocumentReference documentReference = ... //Error produced
```

You need to perform the verification first, confirm that the user is verified then try to access the database.

Another factor could be that you need to refresh your firebase account object, like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().reload();
```

What this does is refresh your account status. Because firebase keeps a reference to your account and that reference is cached it's a useful idea to reload your account, so it is updated. Do this before the `if` statement where you check if your user is verified or not.

You need to take a look at the documentation: [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started). There you would find how to write security rules(the syntax), how to not write insecure rules and how to deploy them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Your explanation is correct but it is because I oversimplified the problem and didn't see the drawback I created. In fact, I changed the rule in my tests to allow not verified emails to perform the Firestore request in performEmailVerification. But the problem of permission denied occures also when I do a Firestore request in checkSomethingOnFirestore().

Comment: That error occurs even if you get your email verified?

Comment: Yes, I checked with the debugger the email was verified before doing the request in checkSomethingOnFirestore()

Comment: I am not completely sure because I made some changes in the code and the rules of my project, but it seems it worked a few weeks ago

Comment: Found your problem, I think. Am going to edit my code.

Comment: In my opinion, the strangest part of the problem is that when I received a permission denied exception, I just have to restart my application (no action on the verification of the email since it is already done), everything goes well.

Comment: Yeah, it well could be that you have to refresh your account status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197659/discussion-between-manu8170-and-gaurav-mall).

Comment: I put firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload() as the very first line in checkSomethingOnFirestore and it works. You saved my day !

Comment: Sorry, but in fact it doesn't solve the problem. I stopped my test before it reaches the request. I still receive a permission denied exception.
I found it strange that the "firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().reload()" that was previously in my code was not executed. In fact, checking with the debugger, it is called twice with the modification I made ! But without any positive result !

Comment: Well, let me see for any other problem

Comment: I've moved to chat, can you go there?

Comment: I validate the answer, even if the problem is not solved. But GauravMall spent some time answering my original question and found a mistake in my sample. Thanks to him !

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your understanding